# C++ sending data but my C# (Unity) Client isn't receiving it

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, networking

I'm currently trying to create a C++ server that can send data to a Unity client. But I'm currently getting the error "SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."

Client (C#):

```
public List<string> Receive()
    {
        //Get data from server
        myServerSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 30000;
        byte[] tempBufferArray = new byte[1024];
        Debug.Log("Recives");
        myServerSocket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Send"));
        Debug.Log("Sent");
        int tempReceivedBytes = myServerSocket.Receive(tempBufferArray);
        Debug.Log("tempReceivedBytes " + tempReceivedBytes);
        Debug.Log("tempBufferArray " + Convert.ToBase64String(tempBufferArray, 0, tempReceivedBytes));
        
        //int tempServerBufferSize = Convert.ToInt32(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(tempBufferList.ToArray()));
        //Debug.Log("tempServerBufferSize " + tempServerBufferSize);



        List<byte> tempBuffer = new List<byte>();
        tempBufferArray = new byte[1024];

        int tempAmountOfBits = myServerSocket.Receive(tempBufferArray);
        string str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(tempBufferArray, 0, tempAmountOfBits);
        Debug.Log("str " + str);

        Debug.Log("tempAmountOfBits " + tempAmountOfBits);
        for (int j = 0; j < tempAmountOfBits; j++)
        {
            tempBuffer.Add(tempBufferArray[j]);
            Debug.Log("Buffer Array " + tempBufferArray[j]);
        }



        //Convert to string and return
        string tempString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tempBuffer.ToArray());
        for (int i = 0; i < tempString.Length; i++)
        {
            tempString = tempString.Replace("\0", string.Empty);
        }

        string[] tempStringArray = tempString.Split('/');
        List<string> tempStringList = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < tempStringArray.Length; i++)
            tempStringList.Add(tempStringArray[i]);


        GameObject.Find("LastRequestText").GetComponent<Text>().text = tempStringList[0];
        tempStringList.RemoveAt(0);

        return tempStringList;
    }
```

Server (C++)

```
void Networking::SendBufferToClient()
{
    char tempMessageChar[MAXCHAR];
    ZeroMemory(tempMessageChar, MAXCHAR);
    int tempBufferRecv = recv(myClientSocket, tempMessageChar, sizeof tempMessageChar, 0);
    if (tempBufferRecv == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "tempBufferRecv == 0 RETURNING" << "\n";
        return;
    }
    std::cout << "Gotten confirmation to send from client" << "\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));


    std::vector<unsigned char*> tempBufferBytes = myPacket->GetBuffer();
    int tempSize = tempBufferBytes.size();
    send(myClientSocket, reinterpret_cast<char*>(tempSize), tempSize, 0);//SEND SIZE
    std::cout << "Sent data to client" << "\n";



    //for (size_t i = 0; i < tempBufferBytes.size(); i++)
    //{
    //  send(myClientSocket, reinterpret_cast<char*>(tempBufferBytes[i]), sizeof(tempBufferBytes[i]), 0);//SEND THE DATA
    //}


    //for (int i = 0; i < tempBufferBytes.size(); i++)
    //{
    //  delete tempBufferBytes[i];
    //}
    //tempBufferBytes.clear();
}
```

While debugging the issue I tried to add a confirmation that the client is receiving data which didn't fix my issue. The data that is currently sent should be an int, to give the client the amount of data the server will send it. The data seems fine on the server-side but something during the sending or casting of the data is causing an issue.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: if the actual data is an `int` then why use a buffer of size `1024` bytes?

Comment: @derHugo No real reason, I have changed it in my code

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<char*>(tempSize)` is nowhere near a valid pointer. What did you intend to send? The vector of `unsigned char*` that you use as a buffer is odd.

Comment: You did not receive the number of character that the server was expecting.  The server is waiting for the AMX number of characters before continuing.

Comment: If you want to send the size first, you should send `&tempSize`, and the size is `sizeof(tempSize)`.

Comment: You dont show how you listen and handle the connection.

Comment: @molbdnilo I used unsigned char* because I believe it's bytes, which I might be wrong about. Which variable type should I use for a buffer? 

I wish to send multiple types of data (different kinds of variables) for example I'm currently sending an int, and then index 2 should be the server's system time (becomes a string), index 3 will probably be an image matrix (Mat) from the OpenCV library.

Comment: "It" is an `int`, and `&tempSize` is a pointer to it. Your cast is trying to treat the number of elements in`tempBufferBytes` as if it were a pointer, which it obviously isn't. (And your explanation of the buffer construction doesn't make much sense. Get much simpler things, like sending a single string, working first.)

Comment: @molbdnilo I was able to make it send by following your advice (`send(myClientSocket, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&tempSize), sizeof(&tempSize), 0);//SEND SIZE`). But now it seems like I have another issue, the cast reinterpret_cast<char*>(&tempSize) "returns" the value "♦" (I wrote it through the servers console) and has the value "\x4" when I hover over it. And on the client side its an empty string (I convert using `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(tempBufferArray, 0, tempReceivedBytes)` and yes I tried with UT8 and it still returned an empty string).

Comment: Not `sizeof(&tempSize)` - that's the size of an `int*` and is wrong. You're sending `sizeof(tempSize)` bytes, so that's what you should use. And why would you expect the number of elements to be a printable character? You're not sending a string, you're sending an integer.

Comment: @molbdnilo I have been able to make it work, thanks very much for helping me!